Is `chrome.storage.onChanged` event triggered when the sync storage is synced in for the first time in a new browser instance?
Suppose a user has an existing Chrome instance (with sync enabled), with an extension that uses chrome.storage.sync. This user now installs a second Chrome instance on a different machine and enables sync. The sync storage content is synced to this new Chrome instance.
In this case, is chrome.storage.onChanged triggered?

Logically, the browser should first getthe storage and only afterwards start the extension so it has all the storage right off the bat, so no event.
